# AngularJS fullCalendar Method GetDate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

I have to use the methode getDate as mentionned in this doc: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/
But i use angular

But i can't access the element "calendar" who is undefined.

My call to the calendar :

```
<div class="calendar col-sm-8" data-ng-model="eventSources"  data-ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" data-calendar="myCalendar" ></div>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar:{
            lang: 'fr',
            weekends: true,
            eventLimite: 4,
            dayClick:function(date, jsEvent, view){
                    //My dayClick function
            eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
                    //My EventClick function
            }
        }
    };
    $scope.date=$scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar.getDate();
```

I also tried :

```
$scope.uiConfig.calendar.fullCalendar.getDate()
```

But fullCalendar is not defined.

Also

```
$scope.uiConfig.calendar.getDate();
```

This time getDate isn't a function

Comment: This is because of a race condition and `$scope.myCalendar` is undefined. Please refer to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41247689/1615594) to watch 'onLoad' events.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$scope.date=$scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar.getDate();
```

To:

```
$scope.date=$scope.myCalendar.fullCalendar('getDate');
```

In addition, assuming you are using angular-ui calendar, your calendar will be part of the array of calendars you have in your controller, which can manage more than one calendar.

From [angular-ui documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar#accessing-the-calendar-object):

### Accessing the calendar object

> It is possible to access a specific calendar object by declaring a
>   name for it on the uiCalendar directive. In this next line we are
>   naming the calendar 'myCalendar'. This will be attached to the
>   uiCalendarConfig constant object, that can be accessed via DI.
>
> ```
> <div ui-calendar="calendarOptions" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar">
> ```
>
> Now the calendar object is available in uiCalendarConfig.calendars:
>
> `uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCalendar`
>
> This allows you to declare any
>   number of calendar objects with distinct names.

Check your references or feel free to fork [my plnkr with angularUi](http://plnkr.co/edit/LbVkCo?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but it does'nt work. "myCalendar"isn't defined. In addition, when i use uiCalendarConfig, this one isn't defined too. Maybe i didn't install all dependencies well...

Comment: It's difficult to know without the definition of your calendar and your controller. Could you provide us a plnkr to reproduce it?

Comment: I add a reference to my plnkr. You can fork it or compare it with your code.

Comment: Using the calendar="myCalendar" approach worked for me. This should be accepted answer.